# How do you write "how much more" in formal notation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

By my understanding asking "how much more" means find the difference, so for example: By how much is $x$ greater than 10? would translate to $x-10=y$.

Found this example in "A Drill Book in Algebra" by Marshal Livingston Perrin.

p.s. this is my first question on this site so let me know if asking you guys to check my answers is an acceptable question, thanks.

Comment: Difference is the only interpretation that really makes sense. But an alternative measure is a quotient. If $x/y=a$, then $x$ is $a$ times larger than $y$. This is a relative measure of "how much larger", rather than an absolute one.

Comment: You wrote what "how much more than 10 means" in notation. Can you clarify what your question is?

Comment: Just meant how/if it could be written as an equation or formula with symbols instead of words.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! @kevinkayaks

Comment: What I don't understand is that it seems that $x-10=y$ *is* "how it could be written as an equation with symbols", so you answered that question already. It's not clear to me what question you want people to answer.

Comment: To your last question, one of the tags you can attach to your post is "solution verification". Posting solutions to problems here in order to have them checked is a very common practice, and one people do not mind. The type of posts that get panned here generally fall into the categories of "do my homework problem for me so I don't have to" or "here is a tiny confused smattering of data concerning my big problem - guess the stuff I couldn't be bothered to include and tell me the answer"